# Updating a row based on a value in another row while performing addition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My query is like,
After SELECTING I am getting values like :

```
    HeadCode      HeadName    NoOfEmp     VisitsMade
    -------------------------------------------------
    A101          ABC          20             5
    M123          DEF          4              1
    L809          LMN          2              10
    B201          XYZ          5              3
```

Now whenever I counter (after SELECTION) HeadCode **B201 - XYZ**, I need to **add** his NoOfEmp and VisitsMade in the row where HeadCode is **A101**.
Like in this example, when I found HeadCode B201, his fields will be added to fields of A101, and the row with HeadCode B201 gets deleted.

```
    HeadCode      HeadName    NoOfEmp     VisitsMade
    -------------------------------------------------
    A101          ABC          25             8
    M123          DEF          4              1
    L809          LMN          2              10
```

Here the row A101 got added with the value of B201, and B201 gets deleted afterwards in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (HeadCode VARCHAR(4), HeadName VARCHAR(3), NoOfEmp INT, VisitsMade INT)

INSERT INTO @tmp
SELECT ... --- your select query

UPDATE @tmp
SET NoOfEmp = NoOfEmp + (SELECT NoOfEmp FROM @tmp WHERE HeadCode = 'B201'),
    VisitsMade = VisitsMade + (SELECT VisitsMade FROM @tmp WHERE HeadCode = 'B201')
WHERE HeadCode = 'A101'

SELECT * FROM @tmp
```

Comment: How does that delete the `B201` row as requested by the OP?

Comment: You can delete all table and insert from @tmp